# Is there a way to track the X/Y/Z positions of controllers in SteamVR, while in-game?

Tags: windows, virtual-reality, steamvr

I am helping with a physical therapy project, that uses VR. I am currently struggling to find a way, to get coordinates of controllers (within the room/relative to headset, whichever) while inside a SteamVR game. Do you know any way of doing that (custom games are out of budget, we're doing some small prototyping for now, to see if it makes sense)? The hardware I am using is the Oculus Quest 2.

I tried searching around the internet, for a premade software solution for my issue, or for any directions, but found only tutorials for Unity, which is not what I want. I need to find a way to capture the coordinates while in another premade game.

EDIT: I found a steamcommunity post about this [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/358720/discussions/0/1333474229086877670/), but I'm not sure how to proceed without good knowledge of C#, I mainly do Python code, will try to tinker around.